# GNOME 3 Num Lock & KVM switch

Tags: keyboard, gnome, kvm-switch, gnome3, gnome-shell

I'm using Arch Linux, and I just upgraded to GNOME 3 with GNOME Shell. I have a KVM switch, which says in the instruction manual to press the Scroll Lock key twice to switch modes. Scroll Locks has never worked for some reason, but pressing Num Lock did work.

Anyway, since I upgraded to GNOME 3, nothing works to switch modes. The indicators on my keyboard say that the button itself is working, but something is different about GNOME 3 that is preventing my KVM from switching.

Anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: Is the KVM a belkin? If so it should be scroll lock twice then the up or down arrow to cycle.

Comment: It's a Trendnet KVM switch TK-209.

Comment: Lol. Swing...and a miss. They claim they'll help you with linux issues if you email them so if it turns out no one here can help you might give that a shot.

Comment: @Blomkvist The fact that they say they support Linux is the reason I purchased their brand. Let's hope that they are true to their word. =)

Comment: I'm rather surprised that any KVM switch needs any cooperation from the OS, it sees the keyboard scancodes before the OS does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've contacted customer support regarding my Trendnet TK-209, but they haven't been able to find a solution. I doubt I will be able to resolve this issue. I'm marking this answer as a community wiki, so if anyone *does* find a solution, feel free to edit my "accepted" answer.

Answer (score 2):

If using any of the usb kvms by Trendnet like TRENDnet Tk-409,
TRENDnet Tk-407 etc on linux distros Install   numlockx then use numlock + numlock to change to another pc.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the following script, and it works. My TRENDnet Tk-409 works with <kbd>numlock</kbd> + <kbd>numlock</kbd>.

Doing a web search, I've found this. Install `numlockx`.

```
#!/bin/bash
numlockx off;sleep 1;  numlockx on; sleep 1; numlockx off
```

I don't know how to associate to a key stroke yet.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation a few years ago when I switched from Windows XP to Vista. A USB KVM I had would not work with the keyboard I had with Vista installed. I wound up purchasing a new keyboard. I had a Razer Tarantula which I replaced with a Saitek Cyborg, and then the switching feature worked fine.

I think, but am not 100% sure, that during the course of my testing I had gotten the Tarantula keyboard to work on the mouse port of the KVM, but then of course I couldn't use the mouse.

Answer (score -1):

I have just found out with my Level-One and exactly the same issue (and my *Hostkey* is <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> + <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd>

Using LevelOne KVM-0422) you can workaround that problem with:

<kbd>Numlock</kbd>, <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd>, <kbd>Numlock</kbd>, <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd>

The sequence has to be fired within the 2 Seconds, but it works beautifully for me now.

Comment: The OP doesn't have a LevelOne KVM